# Interpolate a string every 3 characters starting from the end

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to interpolate a comma into a string for every three digits. Interpolation has to be done from the end of the string. So, the input is:

```
"12345678"
```

And the output should be:

```
"12,345,678"
```

So far, I came up with:

```
"12345678".reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=.)/) { $1 + ',' }.reverse
```

But this seems a bit clunky to me. Any ideas on how to solve this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"12345678".gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\z)/, ",")
```

Comment: `"123456"` gives `",123,456"`

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to Linuxious answer, but a bit shorter:

```
p '12345678'.reverse.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join).join(',').reverse
#=> "12,345,678"
```

Comment: Nice! I knew there had to be something shorter... And anything is better than regexes. As the old saying goes "I had 99 problems. I used regex to fix them. I now have 100 problems" :).

Comment: @Linuxios nice one you wrote. Justin's answer is same as mine but with too short which is good. Its an improvisation of my one. :) :)

Comment: @RubyLovely, I posted a minute or two before yours. So yours is actually an improvisation of mine. :)

Comment: @JustinKo Hey I liked your one.I am not saying you copied my one.rather I said you code it better,which I didn't think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something a little cleaner than your solution (not much, but at least it doesn't involve regexes :) ):

```
"12345678".each_char.to_a.reverse.each_slice(3).to_a.reverse.map {|a| a.reverse.join}.join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"12345678".reverse.chars.each_slice(3).to_a.map{|x| x.join}.join(",").reverse
```

Output:

```
12,345,678
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails [`number_with_delimiter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_delimiter) uses this regex:

```
"12345678".gsub /(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, '\1,'
# => "12,345,678"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, generalised a bit more so it would fit in a method easier, and using the newer Ruby 2 syntax:

```
def intersperse(ns, char: ",", step: 3)
  ys = ""
  ns.chars.each_with_index{|n,i|
    ys << char if i % step == ns.length % step unless i == 0
    ys << n 
  }
  ys
end

ns = "12345678"
intersperse ns
# => "12,345,678"
intersperse ns, step: 2
# => "12,34,56,78"
intersperse ns, char: "!"
# => "12!345!678"
```